# What is the production order of the Monogatari series?

Tags: monogatari-series

It's rather confusing how the story is serialized not in the order of its events. I'd like to know the order in which the animated versions were produced.

---

Turns out the creators of the series are very considerate towards the viewers and include several recap episodes in each season. So although the story is out of order, everything still makes perfect sense and you don't have to bother yourself by figuring out the exact timeline of the original.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Anime

- [Bakemonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/5081/Bakemonogatari) - [化物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%96%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  From the 3<sup>rd</sup> of July 2009 to the 25<sup>th</sup> of June 2010.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: First Season* volume 1 to 2.
- [Nisemonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/11597/Nisemonogatari) - [偽物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%81%BD%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  From the 8<sup>th</sup> of January to the 18<sup>th</sup> of March 2012.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: First Season* volume 4 to 5.
- [Nekomonogatari: Kuro](https://myanimelist.net/anime/15689/Nekomonogatari__Kuro) - [猫物語（黒）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8C%AB%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  On the 31<sup>st</sup> of December 2012.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: First Season* volume 6.
- [Monogatari Series: Second Season](https://myanimelist.net/anime/17074/Monogatari_Series__Second_Season) - 〈物語〉シリーズ セカンドシーズン
  From the 7<sup>th</sup> of July to the 29<sup>th</sup> of December 2013.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Second Season*.

  - Nekomonogatari: Shiro - [猫物語（白）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8C%AB%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    Episodes 1 to 5.
    From volume 1.
  - Kabukimonogatari - [傾物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%BE%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    Episodes 7 to 10.
    From volume 2.
  - Otorimonogatari - [囮物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%AE%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    Episodes 12 to 15.
    From volume 4.
  - Onimonogatari - [鬼物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AC%BC%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    Episodes 17 to 20.
    From volume 5.
  - Koimonogatari - [恋物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%81%8B%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0))
    Episodes 21 to 26.
    From volume 6.
- [Hanamonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/21855/Hanamonogatari) - [花物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8A%B1%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0))
  On the 16<sup>th</sup> of August 2014.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Second Season* volume 3.
- [Tsukimonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/28025/Tsukimonogatari) - [憑物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%86%91%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  On the 31<sup>st</sup> of December 2014.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Final Season* volume 1.
- [Owarimonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31181/Owarimonogatari) - 終物語
  From the 4<sup>th</sup> of October to the 20<sup>th</sup> of December 2015.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Final Season*.

  - Owarimonogatari Joukan - [終物語 （上）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    Episodes 1 to 7.
    From volume 3.
  - Owarimonogatari Chuukan - [終物語 （中）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    Episodes 8 to 13.
    From volume 4.
- [Kizumonogatari I: Tekketsu-hen](https://myanimelist.net/anime/9260/Kizumonogatari_I__Tekketsu-hen) - [傷物語〈Ⅰ鉄血篇〉](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%B7%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  On the 8<sup>th</sup> of January 2016.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: First Season* volume 3.
- [Koyomimonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32268/Koyomimonogatari) - [暦物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9A%A6%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0))
  From the 10<sup>th</sup> of January to the 27<sup>th</sup> of March 2016.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Final Season* volume 2.
- [Kizumonogatari II: Nekketsu-hen](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31757/Kizumonogatari_II__Nekketsu-hen) - [傷物語〈Ⅱ熱血篇〉](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%B7%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  On the 19<sup>th</sup> of August 2016.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: First Season* volume 3.
- [Kizumonogatari III: Reiketsu-hen](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31758/Kizumonogatari_III__Reiketsu-hen) - [傷物語〈Ⅲ冷血篇〉](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%B7%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  On the 6<sup>th</sup> of January 2017.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: First Season* volume 3.
- [Owarimonogatari 2nd Season](https://myanimelist.net/anime/35247/Owarimonogatari_2nd_Season) - 終物語
  From the 12<sup>th</sup> to the 13<sup>th</sup> of August 2017.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Final Season*.

  - Owarimonogatari Gekan - [終物語 （下）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 5.
- [Zoku Owarimonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36999/Zoku_Owarimonogatari) - [続・終物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B6%9A%E3%83%BB%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
  On the 10<sup>th</sup> of November 2018.
  Light novel: *Monogatari Series: Final Season* volume 6.

## Light Novels

- [Monogatari Series: First Season](https://myanimelist.net/manga/14893/Monogatari_Series__First_Season) - 〈物語〉シリーズ ファーストシーズン
  From the 1<sup>st</sup> of November 2006 to the 28<sup>th</sup> of July 2010.
  Containing:

  - Bakemonogatari - [化物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%96%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 1 to 2.
  - Kizumonogatari - [傷物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%B7%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 3.
  - Nisemonogatari - [偽物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%81%BD%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 4 to 5.
  - Nekomonogatari: Kuro - [猫物語（黒）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8C%AB%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 6.
- [Monogatari Series: Second Season](https://myanimelist.net/manga/23751/Monogatari_Series__Second_Season) - 〈物語〉シリーズ セカンドシーズン
  From the 27<sup>th</sup> of October 2010 to the 20<sup>th</sup> of December 2011.
  Containing:

  - Nekomonogatari: Shiro - [猫物語（白）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8C%AB%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 1.
  - Kabukimonogatari - [傾物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%82%BE%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 2.
  - Hanamonogatari - [花物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8A%B1%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0))
    From volume 3.
  - Otorimonogatari - [囮物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%AE%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 4.
  - Onimonogatari - [鬼物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AC%BC%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 5.
  - Koimonogatari - [恋物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%81%8B%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0))
    From volume 6.
- [Monogatari Series: Final Season](https://myanimelist.net/manga/44227/Monogatari_Series__Final_Season) - 〈物語〉シリーズ ファイナルシーズン
  From the 28<sup>th</sup> of September 2012 to the 18<sup>th</sup> of September 2014.
  Containing:

  - Tsukimonogatari - [憑物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%86%91%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 1.
  - Koyomimonogatari - [暦物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9A%A6%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E_(%E8%A5%BF%E5%B0%BE%E7%B6%AD%E6%96%B0))
    From volume 2.
  - Owarimonogatari Joukan - [終物語 （上）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 3.
  - Owarimonogatari Chuukan - [終物語 （中）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 4.
  - Owarimonogatari Gekan - [終物語 （下）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 5.
  - Zoku Owarimonogatari - [続・終物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B6%9A%E3%83%BB%E7%B5%82%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 6.
- [Monogatari Series: Off Season](https://myanimelist.net/manga/93097/Monogatari_Series__Off_Season) - 〈物語〉シリーズ オフシーズン
  From the 5<sup>th</sup> of October 2015 to the 11<sup>th</sup> of January 2017.
  Containing:

  - Orokamonogatari - [愚物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%84%9A%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 1.
  - Wazamonogatari - [業物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A5%AD%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 2.
  - Nademonogatari - [撫物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%92%AB%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 3.
  - Musubimonogatari - [結物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%90%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 4.
- [Monogatari Series: Monster Season](https://myanimelist.net/manga/108177/Monogatari_Series__Monster_Season) - 〈物語〉シリーズ モンスターシーズン
  Since the 20<sup>th</sup> of July 2017.
  Containing:

  - Shinobumonogatari - [忍物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BF%8D%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 1.
  - Yoimonogatari - [宵物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%B5%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E)
    From volume 2.
  - Amarimonogatari - [余物語](https://kuromitsuha.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/04/22/173523)
    From volume 3.
  - Ōgimonogatari - 扇物語
    From volume 4.
  - Shinomonogatari Jō - 死物語（上）
    From volume 5.
  - Shinomonogatari Ge - 死物語（下）
    From volume 6.

## Manga

There is [a manga version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogatari_(series)#Manga). However I don't know if it contains any of the same stories (e.g. Bakemonogatari) or sub stories (e.g. Hitagai Crab).

- Bakemonogatari (manga) - 化物語
  Japanese: From the 15<sup>th</sup> of June 2018 to the 17<sup>th</sup> of October 2019.
  English: Since the 1<sup>st</sup> of October 2019.
  Contains 7 volumes.

## Short Stories

This isn't a complete list, as [a lot of the short stories are one-shots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monogatari_novels#List_of_short_short_stories).

- [Bakemonogatari Anime Complete Guidebook](https://myanimelist.net/manga/24499/Bakemonogatari_Short_Stories) - 化物語アニメコンプリートガイドブック
  On the 28<sup>th</sup> of October 2010.
- [Nisemonogatari Anime Complete Guidebook](https://myanimelist.net/manga/90322/Nisemonogatari_Short_Stories) - 偽物語アニメコンプリートガイドブック
  On the 27<sup>th</sup> of September 2012.
- [Anime Monogatari Series Heroine Book](https://myanimelist.net/manga/86670/Monogatari_Series_Heroine_Hon) - アニメ＜物語＞シリーズヒロイン本
  Since the 29<sup>th</sup> of October 2013.

## Additional Content

- [Bakemonogatari Recap](https://myanimelist.net/anime/6948/Bakemonogatari_Recap) - 化物語
  On the 7<sup>th</sup> of August 2009.
- [Naisho no Hanashi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36725/Naisho_no_Hanashi) - ナイショの話
  On the 2<sup>nd</sup> of February 2012.
  A song.
- [Nekomonogatari: Kuro Recap](https://myanimelist.net/anime/38971/Nekomonogatari__Kuro_Recap) - 「化物語」ダイジェストムービー
  On the 6<sup>th</sup> of March 2013.
- [Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica Movie 3: Hangyaku no Monogatari - Magica Quartet x Nisioisin](https://myanimelist.net/anime/23831/Mahou_Shoujo_Madoka%E2%98%85Magica_Movie_3__Hangyaku_no_Monogatari_-_Magica_Quartet_x_Nisioisin)
  On the 26<sup>th</sup> of October 2013.
  Short videos instructing movie etiquette. Crossover with [Mahou Shoujo Madoka★Magica](https://myanimelist.net/anime/9756/Mahou_Shoujo_Madoka%E2%98%85Magica?q=Mahou).
- [Okitegami Kyouko no Bibouroku x Monogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32191/Okitegami_Kyouko_no_Bibouroku_x_Monogatari) - 『掟上今日子の備忘録』×〈物語〉
  On the 31<sup>st</sup> of December 2014.
  A short promotional video as a crossover and promoting [Okitegami Kyouko no Bibouroku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/90993/Okitegami_Kyouko_no_Bibouroku).
- [Nisekoimonogatari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/30514/Nisekoimonogatari) - ニセコイモノガタリ
  On the 1<sup>st</sup> of April 2015.
  An April fools crossover trailer with [Nisekoi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/18897/Nisekoi).
- [Koyomi History](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37139/Koyomi_History) - こよみヒストリー
  Sometime during 2016.
  A short recap.

Answer (score 17):

1. The first 12 episodes of **Bakemonogatari** aired on TV weekly from July 3 - September 25, 2009. Episodes 13-15 of Bakemonogatari were webcasted from November 3 - June 25, 2010.
2. **Nisemonogatari** (11 episodes) aired on TV weekly from January 7 - March 17, 2012.
3. **Nekomonogatari [Black]** (4 episodes) aired on TV as a special on December 31, 2012.
4. **Monogatari Second Season** (consisting of Neko [White], Kabuki, Otori, Oni, and Koi; 26 episodes including 3 recaps) aired on TV weekly from July 6, 2013 - December 28, 2013.
5. **Hanamonogatari** (also called "Monogatari Second Season + α" ["plus alpha"]; 5 episodes) aired as a special on August 16, 2014.
6. **Tsukimonogatari** (4 episodes) aired as a special on December 31, 2014.

See [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4695/what-is-the-chronological-order-of-the-monogatari-series) for information on the in-universe *chronological* order of the series.

---

Note also that the *publication* order of the light novels is not the same as the *production* order of the animated series. There are two key differences.

- Kizumonogatari, which was published between Bake and Nise, has not yet been animated. It was [announced](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2010-07-28/nisioisin-kizumonogatari-light-novel-gets-anime) in July 2010 that Kizumonogatari would receive a film adaptation. As of this writing (over four years later), no such adaptation has been produced, nor is there even any reason to believe that anybody actually planned to produce a film version of Kizu. Many speculate that Kizumonogatari is an elaborate practical joke by Shaft.
- Hanamonogatari, which was published between Kabuki and Otori, was not animated until after Otori, Oni, and Koi.

Comment: Looks like Hanamonogatari will be titled Monogatari:Second Season+α  http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=714937

Comment: with Monogatari Second Season, is the production order of the smaller series you have listed in order of production order as well?

Comment: @Memor-X The Second Season arcs (besides Hana) were animated in the same order they were published, yes: Neko [Black] → Neko [White] → Kabuki → (Hana) → Otori → Oni → Koi.

Comment: http://anilist.co/anime/21262/Owarimonogatari is airing soon